# Creating Object and set Properties

Tags: javascript, oop

Using the following object as an example

```
var CarAd = function(car){
 this.year = car.year;
 this.model = car.model;
 this.make = car.make;
 this.formattedDescription = function(){
   return "this is a " + this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model;
 }
}
```

I would like that the value for formattedDescription be available upon instancing the object but as it stands, formattedDescription() will, of course, not execute until it is called. How would this be refactored?

Comment: Please don't add the solution to your question. You can post a separate answer and then remove the solution from your question. You can, but don't have to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is hacky, but you could automatically call the function and assign it's value to formattedDescription.

```
var CarAd = function(car){
 this.year = car.year;
 this.model = car.model;
 this.make = car.make;
 this.formattedDescription = (function(){
   return "this is a " + this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model;
 })()
}
```

Edit...This feels more natural:

```
var CarAd = function(car){
 this.year = car.year;
 this.model = car.model;
 this.make = car.make;
 function createFormattedDescription () {
   return "this is a " + this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model;
 };
 this.formattedDescription = createFormattedDescription();
}
```

Comment: I did have to make one small change though since it appears that inside the annon self executing func that 'this' is not accessable.

Comment: You did mention that his seems a bit hacky.. I wonder, is there a more appropriate way create a class where when instanced the instance has formatted data, similar to, say, a property with a getter and setter?

Comment: Thanks @MarkHollas. I changed it so that it uses an actual (private) function. This feels better at least :)

Answer (score 0):

make `this.formattedDescription` as a self executed function like:

```
this.formattedDescription = (function(){
   return "this is a " + this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model;
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as this:

```
var makecar = function(year, model, make){
    return {
        year: year,
        model: model,
        make: make,
        description: "this is a " + year + " " + make + " " + model
    };
};
```